# Why the value webservice returns was not xml

Tags: asp.net, web-services, shared-libraries

```
webservice.PService pService = new Project.webservice.PService();
var v3 = passportService.HelloWorld();
Response.Write(v3);
```

I debugged it and found that v3 was string. Why? Should not a webservcie always return xml?
The webservice was:

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Edit:
What if I want an object or a list of objects to be returned by the webservcie?

Comment: The webservice returns XML, your call is extracting the relevant part for you, so you don't have to deal with it...

Comment: Also, XML **is** a string, just with special format.

Comment: The HelloWorld was a demo. What if I want an object or a list of objects to be returned by the webservcie?

Comment: only that object list needs to be serializable , then you can return that object list.

Comment: @Furqan My work is about processing data. Like resumes. So can you give me an example about what is not serializable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you might want to start with [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Then have a look at [returning objects](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/05/26/737.aspx).

Whilst the webservice transport layer uses XML, there's an awful lot of stuff in there that your application code typically isn't going to care about, which is why the client proxies strip it all out for you, so that you're left with the the bits that you're interested in.

As long as the object you want to return from your `WebMethod` is serializable, you should be able to just define it as a return type and it'll get encoded for you.  When you generate the client side proxy, a similar object will be created for the request to be deserialized into.

Returning collections of objects from your `WebMethod` is essentially the same, although it's worth noting that [`List<T>` is converted to an Array, over the wire](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/e45222f3-d0a5-465b-8718-39fc3f9406e2/).

Comment: So I just have to Define a class in Webservice and return it? The .net framework will do the rest for me?

Comment: @hbrlovehaku: In most cases, yes, that should be enough, as long as the right bits are public / serializable.

Answer (score 1):

The web service takes an object, and serialises it to XML, and sends that XML back to the client. The client/proxy parses that XML, and deserialises it back to an object. The type returned is determined by your web method signature. If you wanted to see the original XML, you could do so by inspecting the HTTP messages, but the point of using the proxy is that it does the conversion for you.